# tikz-cd doesn't know the label key

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I see there is a ton of questions concerning `tikz-cd` errors already, and I come to join the club because none of these solved my problem. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[draft, 12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
   \theoremstyle{definition}
      \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
      \newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
      \newtheorem*{review}{Review}
   \theoremstyle{plain}
      \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
      \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
   \theoremstyle{remark}
      \newtheorem{example}{Example}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{hyperref}
   \hypersetup{colorlinks = true}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\ZC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\ZR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\CS}{\mathcal{S}}
\newcommand{\PC}{\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\ph}{\,\cdot\,}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
\newcommand{\covX}{\overline{X}}
\newcommand{\covx}{\overline{x}}
\newcommand{\covf}{\overline{f}}
\newcommand{\covg}{\overline{g}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
   \covX\arrow[dr,"p"]\arrow[rr,"h"] & & \covX'\arrow[dl,"p'"] \\
   & X &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And here is the error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/"p"'
```

Now I really can't imagine why this doesn't work, since I believe the standard way of labeling an arrow in `tikz-cd` is by simply adding the name between double quotes to the list of options of the arrow, as I did; actually, many examples I found around do like that. What is even more intriguing is that I used the same code in a beamer presentation (using a fragile frame) three days ago and it worked without problem! Hence I am quite lost. I suppose something is wrong with my preamble, but I cannot figure out what is wrong or missing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fragment of your code inform me that your code tikz-cd work correctly. The problem was the babel `icelandic`!!! I hold `icelandic` babel and add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`. Thus all the code work correctly.

```
\documentclass[draft, 12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,icelandic]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\covX}{\overline{X}}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
   \covX\arrow[dr,"p"]\arrow[rr,"h"] & & \covX'\arrow[dl,"p'"] \\
   & X &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, I see that removing ```icelandic``` solves the problem. Unfortunately, I cannot take that out, since it is a shared project. For now I have dropped ```tikz-cd``` and started using ```xy```, which doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: @Albert Hi, have you seen last my edit of 55 secs ago? I have put \usetikzlibrary{babel} and you can use icelandic babel.